# Snowflake: Is it possible to pass few Columns (DataFrame) into Snowpark UDTF ( Python language)?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I wrote UDTF on Snowpark/Python which receives one Column as argument, all works fine.
Is it possible (no documentation regarding this feature) to pass few columns (i.e. DataFrame) into UDTF ?

My code below dosn't work, exception is  *"TypeError: 'TABLE FUNCTION' expected Column or str, got: <class 'snowflake.snowpark.dataframe.DataFrame'>"*

Can anybody suggest how to do this (except concatenating few columns into one and pass one column into UDTF)?

```
import uuid
@udtf(output_schema=["c1","c2","x"], 
      input_types =[StringType(), StringType(), IntegerType()],
      name="udft_two_col_test", 
      replace=True, 
      session=ses)
class udft_two_col_test:
    def process(self, c1:str, c2:str, n: int) -> Iterable[Tuple[str, str, str]]: 
        for i in range(n):
            yield (c1, c2, f'{n}-{c1}-{c2}')

            
df = ses.create_dataframe([str(uuid.uuid4()).split('-') for i in range(1,10,1)], schema=['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5'])
df.sort('c1','c2').show()

------------------------------------------------
|"C1"      |"C2"  |"C3"  |"C4"  |"C5"          |
------------------------------------------------
|125a9845  |f7e2  |48dd  |b51c  |42ba82531fe7  |
|136da5dc  |62cb  |47c0  |98f9  |4182421e6d2b  |
|300380e2  |b365  |4d6a  |8d6b  |1092e4c24ec8  |
|3d9d9882  |0fb2  |4209  |bf11  |4341b0336946  |
|43c4147d  |1603  |4548  |ad8e  |4df50cddd682  |
|9e1024ca  |61d5  |404d  |88f8  |79393083eb30  |
|bf25e899  |5697  |4c36  |8533  |e3009c68ce9b  |
|d6dd677f  |035b  |49e7  |9236  |316741579f3c  |
|f4b83587  |26e1  |48cf  |8563  |0586ccb6602e  |
------------------------------------------------

df.join_table_function("udft_two_col_test", df["c1","c2"], lit(3)).sort('c1','c2').show(100)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
...
---> 17 df.join_table_function("udft_two_col_test", df["c1","c2"], lit(3)).sort('c1','c2').show(100)
...
TypeError: 'TABLE FUNCTION' expected Column or str, got: <class 'snowflake.snowpark.dataframe.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: Might help to input df.c1 and df.cd2 separately.
It is definitely possible, I was just able to do it using sql.
Here's documentation that might help: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-table.html#using-a-table-as-input-to-a-table-function

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the columns one by one:

```py
df.join_table_function(udft_two_col_test_dec("c1", "c2", lit(3))).show()
# or
df.join_table_function(udft_two_col_test_dec.name, "c1", "c2", lit(3)).show()
```

In the documentation of [`join_table_function`](https://docs.snowflake.com/ko/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/api/snowflake.snowpark.DataFrame.join_table_function.html) you see an example like this:

```py
df.join_table_function(split_to_table(df["addresses"], lit(" "))).show()
```

where `df["addresses"]` is a single column of the dataframe, and `lit(" ")` is another column.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

It is possible with UDTFs (User Defined Table Functions) which comes with v0.7.0

Here is an example:

```
from collections import Counter
from typing import Iterable, Tuple
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import lit
class MyWordCount:
    def __init__(self):
        self._total_per_partition = 0

    def process(self, s1: str) -> Iterable[Tuple[str, int]]:
        words = s1.split()
        self._total_per_partition = len(words)
        counter = Counter(words)
        yield from counter.items()

    def end_partition(self):
        yield ("partition_total", self._total_per_partition)

udtf_name = "word_count_udtf"
word_count_udtf = session.udtf.register(
    MyWordCount, ["word", "count"], name=udtf_name, is_permanent=False, replace=True)


# Call it by its name
df1 = session.table_function(udtf_name, lit("w1 w2 w2 w3 w3 w3"))
df1.show()
-----------------------------
|"WORD"           |"COUNT"  |
-----------------------------
|w1               |1        |
|w2               |2        |
|w3               |3        |
|partition_total  |6        |
-----------------------------

# Call it by the returned callable instance
df2 = session.table_function(word_count_udtf(lit("w1 w2 w2 w3 w3 w3")))
df2.show()
-----------------------------
|"WORD"           |"COUNT"  |
-----------------------------
|w1               |1        |
|w2               |2        |
|w3               |3        |
|partition_total  |6        |
-----------------------------
```